# How does low-level character encodings work?

Tags: character-encoding

let's say, i have a textfile  called  sometext.txt
it has a line - "Sic semper tyrannis" which is (correct me if i'm wrong..)

```
83 105 99 32 115 101 109 112 101 114 32 116 121
114 97 110 110 105 115
```

(in decimal ASCII)

When i read this line from file using standard library file i/o routines, i don't perform any character encodings work.. (or do i??)

The question is:
Which software component actually converts 0s and 1s into characters(i.e. contains algorithm for converting 0s and 1s into characters)?? Is it OS component?? Which one??

Comment: Which standard library? (C? Ruby?) What do you mean by characters? If the concept of being an "A" or a "B", there's no conversion - 01000001 is the same thing as "A". If you mean the shape of the character on screen or printer, it's the font (which is lately in OS or graphics library, in older computers in computer or printer ROM)

Comment: You clearly don't have enough understanding of the matter. Do some reading first. There is a major difference between encoding characters and displaying them.

Comment: @Amadan: "01000001 is the same thing as 'A'" is the exact statement that one should avoid: A is only that bitsequence in the context of a certain encoding. "A is encoded as 01000001 in ASCII" or "A is encoded as 01000001 in UTF-8" are true, but it is not the general case.

Comment: He said "in decimal ASCII", I was answering in context. I could have been clearer.

Comment: lets say Windows. reading characters from textfile by using appropriate Win API function. Does this function check  mapping, find default font and display it?? Or What??

Comment: Let's say Windows. There are functions for reading bytes from a file, functions for allocating buffers, functions for putting bytes in buffers, functions for encoding strings, functions for allocating device contexts and functions for actually writing a text buffer to the screen. I must be missing a few steps here too. And that is just because Windows does still do a lot of work internally. If you were trying to draw the full range of (unicode) characters in DOS, you'd first have to design a font, have to invite unicode4Dos and then have to interpret each byte to see which character it is.

Comment: And you could try to use one consequetive question mark instead of two all the time. It may make you look less mentally ill. :-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's *all* a bunch of 1's and 0's.

An ASCII "A" is just the letter displayed when the value (01000001b, or 0x41 or 65 dec) is "encountered" (depend on context, naturally). There is no "conversion"; it's just a different view of the same thing defined by an [accepted mapping](http://www.asciitable.com/).

---

Unicode (and other multi-byte) character sets often use different encodings; in UTF-8 (a Unicode encoding), for instance, a single Unicode character can be mapped as 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes depending upon the character. *Unicode encoding conversion often takes place in the IO libraries that come as part of a language or runtime*; however, a Unicode-aware operating system also needs to understand a Unicode encoding itself (in system calls) so the line can be blurred.

UTF-8 has the nice property that all normal ASCII characters map to a single byte which makes it the most compatible Unicode encoding with traditional ASCII.

Comment: but what software component is responsible for displaying "A" when the bit sequence (01000001b, or 0x41 or 65 dec) is encountered?? Compiler?? OS?? or What??

Comment: @DrS You missed the terminal (tty) and the GUI as candidates, there, which is the usual case these days.

Comment: @DrStrangeLove It **depends on what actually wants to display "A"** ;-)

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: It's whatever renders your string to screen or print. In Windows C programs, it's Windows OS functions. In Java, it's be Swing functions. In terminal, it's BIOS. In old printers, it's printer's ROM.

Comment: @pst i see.. but what are possible options?? for example??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove A <- your browser was nice enough show ("render") that A :)

Comment: another question: how does atoi function relate to this?? Is it implemented in software Amadan mentioned above??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove `atoi` converts the *string which represents the number* (to use humans who like to read text and work in base often) into the numeric value itself.

Comment: you mean converting "25" to 25??

Answer (score 4):

First, I recommend that you read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

---

> When i read this line from file using
>   standard library file i/o routines, i
>   don't perform any character encodings
>   work.. (or do i??)

That depends heavily on *which* standard library you mean.

In C, when you write:

```
FILE* f = fopen("filename.txt", "w");
fputs("Sic semper tyrannis", f);
```

No encoding conversion is performed; the `char`s in the string are just written to the file as-is (except for line breaks).  (Encoding *is* relevant when you're editing the source file.)

But in Python 3.x, when you write:

```
f = open('filename.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
f.write('Sic semper tyrannis')
```

The `write` function performs an internal conversion from the UTF-16/32 encoding of the Python `str` types to the UTF-8 encoding used on disk.

---

> The question is: Which software
>   component actually converts 0s and 1s
>   into characters(i.e. contains
>   algorithm for converting 0s and 1s
>   into characters)?? Is it OS
>   component?? Which one??

The **decoding function** (like [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`bytes.decode`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-and-byte-array-methods)) for the appropriate character encoding converts the bytes into Unicode **code points**, which are integers that uniquely identify characters.  A **font** converts code points to **glyphs**, the images of the characters that appear on screen or paper.

Answer (score 1):

> Which software component actually converts 0s and 1s into characters(i.e. contains algorithm for converting 0s and 1s into characters)?

This depends on what languge you're using. For example, Python has character encoding functions:

```
>>> f = open( ...., 'rb')
>>> data = f.read()
>>> data.decode('utf-8')
u'café'
```

Here, Python has converted a sequence of bytes into a Unicode string. The exact component is typically a library or program in userspace, but some compilers need knowledge of character encodings.

Underneath, it's *all* a sequence of bytes, which are 1s and 0s. However, given a sequence of bytes, *which* characters do these represent? ASCII is one such "character encoding", and tells us how to encode or decode A-Z, a-z, and a few more. There are **many** others, noteably UTF-8 (an encoding of Unicode). In the end, *if you're dealing with text, you need to know what character encoding it is encoded with.*

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing (well, not so much) to do's with 0s and 1s. Most character encodings work with entire bytes of 8 bits. Each of the numbers you wrote represents a single byte. In ASCII, every character is a single byte. Besides that, ASCII is a subset of ANSI and UTF-8, making it compatible with the most used character sets. ASCII contains only the first half of the byte range. Chars upto 127.

For ANSI you need some encoding. ANSI specifies the characters in the upper half of the byte range. In UTF-8, these ANSI characters don't exist. Instead, these last 128 bytes represent *part of* a character. A whole character is made of 2 to 4 bytes. Except those 128 ASCII characters. They are still the same old single byte characters. I think this is mainly done because if UTF-8 wouldn't be compatible with ASCII, there is no way Americans would have adopted it. ;-)

But yes, the OS does have various functions to work with character encodings. Where they are depends on the OS and platform, but if I read your question right, you're not really looking for some specific API. Your question cannot be answered that concrete. There are numerous ways to work with characters, and these is a major difference between working with the actual character data and writing them to the screen. (difference between character and font).

Comment: ANSI needs no more "encoding" than ASCII; it's just an extended mapping across 8bits. However, I do like this answer in general +1.

Comment: "ASCII is a subset of ANSI" is nonsense… "ANSI" is not a valid encoding and is a poor term — it usually means  the current Windows code page, which can be any number of encodings. Some of these code pages are just "ASCII with the stuff in the upper 128-255 range)", some are more complex. The whole bit about "last 128 bytes represent part" and "whole character is … 2 to 4 bytes … except those 128 ASCII characters" is nonsense, and isn't true for the default Windows installation on American computers, which uses Windows-1252, a constant-length encoding where each character is always 1 byte.

Comment: You're reading it wrong. ANSI is indeed a set of different encodings (or code pages, actually), but can be described as *extended ASCII*. ASCII uses only the first 7 bits of a byte. If you use the 8th bit too, you can call it extended ASCII or ANSI. The code page does tell you what those upper range characters mean, but the lower range is always the ASCII set. So ANSI is an encoding in which you need to know a parameter, the code page, to be able to interpret the higher, 'non American' characters.

Comment: In ANSI each character is always 1 byte, as I've written. I'm talking about UTF-8 when I wrote that it also contains characters that are made out of more than one byte. UTF-8 still contains ASCII but the upper range characters are actually only *part of* a multi-byte character set. Please read before making comments about nonsense.

Comment: I took the liberty to mark the answer as edited, so you can reconsider your downvote. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Like DrStrangeLove says, it's 1's & 0's all the way to your display screen and beyond  - the 'A' character is an array of pixels whose color/brightness is defined by bits in the display driver. Turning that pixel array into an understandable character needs a bioElectroChemical video camera connected to 10^11 threshold logic gates running an adaptive, massively-parallel OS and apps that no-one understands, especially after a few beers

Not exactly sure what you're asking.  The 0's and 1's from the file are blocked up into the bytes that can represent ASCII codes by the disk driver - it will only read/write blocks of eight bits. The ASCII code bytes are rendered into displayable bitmaps by the display driver using the chosen font.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: display driver- you mean computer monitor driver?? Or video card driver??